# What do squared brackets do to an argument of a function when being used inside an if/else statement?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I dont really know if the title makes sense at all but i dont really know how to ask the question in the first place so i'll just show the code and hopefully someone can make sense of it? Thank you!

My concern is the elif statement where it says ((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):
Why is the [1] there for both inputs? I don't understand why they are there at all or even why it has to be 1?

```
player_score = 0

computer_score = 0

options = [('Rock',0), ('Paper',1), ('Scissors',2)]

tie_score = 0


def clicked(player_input):

    global player_score, computer_score, rock_use, paper_use, scissors_use,tie_score

    computer_input = get_computer_choice()

    player_choice_label.config(text='Your Selected : ' + player_input[0])

    computer_choice_label.config(text='Computer Selected : ' + computer_input[0])

    if (player_input == computer_input):
        tie_score += 1
        tie_counter.config(text='Ties: ' + str(tie_score))
        winner_label.config(text="Tie")
    elif ((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):
        player_score += 1
        winner_label.config(text="You Won!!!")
        player_score_label.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(player_score))
    else:
        computer_score += 1
        winner_label.config(text="Computer Won!!!")
        computer_score_label.config(text='Computer Score : ' + str(computer_score))










def get_computer_choice():

    return options[randint(0,2)]


#Buttons

rock_butt = Button(root, image=rock_photo,command=lambda:clicked(options[0]))

paper_butt = Button(root, image=paper_photo ,command=lambda:clicked(options[1]))

scissors_butt = Button(root, image=scissor_photo ,command=lambda: clicked(options[2]))
```

Comment: Squared brackets are used for indexing a iterable.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is tricky.  It is a compact test to see if the player won a round of "Rock, Paper, Scissors."  To understand the code you need to take it in steps:

1. The game options were defined as tuples: ("Rock", 0"), ("Paper", 1), ("Scissors", 2).
2. The fields in a tuple can be indexed using square brackets: the expression ("Rock", 0)[1] resolves as 0.
3. Here is the tricky part: (0 - 2) % 3, (1 - 0) % 3, and (2 - 1) % 3 all resolve as 1.
4. Put it all together and you can see the code in question will identify all winning combinations for the user.

```
elif ((player_input[1] - computer_input[1]) % 3 == 1):
        player_score += 1
        winner_label.config(text="You Won!!!")
        player_score_label.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(player_score))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That cleared it all up. I just started learning python and cant believe i didnt put that together!

Comment: LOL - I am an experienced Python developer and it took me a while to figure it out.  The use of the modulo operator in particular is at best counter-intuitive, and at worst pure evil. ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Whether the []-s are inside an if/else statement or not, they do the same thing. Which is in your case, used as an index for an iterable. Indexing starts at 0 in python, so your case is [1] refers to the second item in player_inupt and in computer_input.
It seems like either of player_input or computer input would be the following:
options[0] or options[1], or options[2] (same brackets as u can see, doing the same indexing). options[0] returns ('Rock', 0), of these two, the main function does not care for 'Rock' but it cares for the number 0 - which is the second of the two - which will be index[1]. (indexing starts at 0.)
options[0][0] is 'Rock', options[2][1] is  , to further clarify the point.
Hope this helps, and as a side-note the code itself does look a bit strange, maybe look around for different tutorials if this was copied out from somewhere unreliable.